# show last updated date time field in address magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-address

I want to show a text field in address field which can show the last updated date time in customer address section in magento admin.

I have this field in every address a customer can have 2-3 or more address then this field should be every time show in magento admin.

If any one have any idea and any code script please let me know show I can Integrate this.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the fields as if they are part of customer address attributes or table.

```
$configOptions = array(
           'label'     => 'Updated Date',
           'name'      => 'updated_at',
           'style'     => 'display:block;'
);
$fieldset->addField('updated_at', 'text',$configOptions);
```

For this extend the

> Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Addresses

block in your local folder and edit the `initForm()` action.